# mongodb is not start after restoring /var/lib/mongodb manually

Tags: mongodb

Our server's raid failed today. Right now we have a zip file of mongodbPath but after we extract it, we can not start mongo db again.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please include a clear problem description and if possible some minimal code. Explain what you have already tried etc. pp. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searches and contacting with MongoDB's support we fond out that we rsync MongoDB directory when it was writing. 
So we cannot restore data and we had data lost! 
If you want to use rsync for getting backup of MongoDB you should stop it. 
[This may help.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/)